# Grep exact match "/etc"

Tags: search, grep

I would like to make an exact search of the string `/etc`, in the next file:

```
  -14: _etcrpm    /etc/rpm
  -14: _nssdb_path       /etc/pki/nssdb
  -14: _rpmds_ldconfig_cache      /etc/ld.so.cache
  -14: _sysconfdir        /etc
    -DKDE_DISTRIBUTION_TEXT="%(cat /etc/mandriva-release)" \
  -14: distepoch  %(sed -e 's#.*release\ \(\S*\).*#\1#' /etc/release)
  -14: distro_class       %(. /etc/sysconfig/system; echo $META_CLASS)
```

I would like that in the output of grep, appears the line that contains **only** "/etc"

```
    -14: _sysconfdir        /etc
```

Can somebody help me with that?

Thank you

Comment: Please mention what have you tried so far and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
grep -P "(?<=\s)/etc(?=\s|$)" file
```

Or:

```
grep -E "\s/etc(\s|$)" file
```

Or:

```
grep  "[[:space:]]/etc\([[:space:]]\|$\)" file
```

Output:

```
  -14: _sysconfdir        /etc
```

`-P` is for Perl regex.
`-E` is for extended regex.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could use awk to check if the last word is "/etc"

```
awk '$NF == "/etc" file
```